# Flutter Custom Navigation Bar with custom shape

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How can I make custom nav bar like below photo?
Thank you!

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1C9sk.jpg)

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66135583/how-to-create-this-type-of-bottom-navigation-bar-with-curved-background/66138994#66138994

Comment: Also, RetroPortal Studio has a very nice tutorial on this https://youtu.be/1ToqYMSnNhA